# The output of this program seems to print '5 0 1' instead of '5 1 1' . I'm unable to figure out why?

Tags: c++, function, class, object

So this program's printing `5 0 1`. Shouldn't it be `5 1 1` ? `data1++` does increment `f1.data1` by `1`. Where really does the `0` come from? I'm using multiple functions because I've just started learning Objects and Classes and am trying to make as many possibilities as possible. This is really confusing me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo
{
    private:

        int data1; //private data member

    public:

        foo(): data1(0) //Constructor initialising it to 0.
        { }

    void func(foo,foo);

    void display(foo fg) const
    {
        cout<<data1;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<fg.data1;
    }
};

void foo::func(foo ff,foo fg)
{
    ff.data1=5;
    data1++;
    ff.display(fg);
    cout<<endl<<data1<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    foo f1,f2;
    f1.func(f2,f1);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You could step through in a debugger to find out what's going on.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO please take [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) And also [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: One hint is that you are passing parameters by value - creating copies. How many copies do you have? What happens to a copy when you update the original?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @PeteBecker, yeah I could actually use \n instead of using endl. Just a habit of mine.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, shall try that thanks!

Comment: @BoPersson that's actually a very good point. I'll try doing it via reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are three objects in `foo::func`.  They are `*this`, `ff` and `fg`. 
`foo::func` is pass-by-value. So `fg` is a copy of `f1` and `*this` is `f1`. 
So `data1++` makes `this->data1 == 1` but `fg.data1` is still `0`.
Note: Debugging the program step and step is a good way.

Answer (score 1):

Walking through main:

```
foo f1,f2;
```

default constructs `f1` and `f2` so both their `data1` members are 0

```
f1.func(f2,f1);
```

Calls `func` on the `f1` instance passing in a copy of `f2` for parameter `ff` and a copy of `f1` for parameter `fg`

Inside `func`:

```
ff.data1=5;
```

Will set the `data1` member of  `f2` to 5

```
data1++;
```

Bumps the `data1` member of `f1` from 0 to 1, `fg` remains unaffected

```
ff.display(fg);
```

Will display the `data1` member of  `f2` (which is 5), new line, and then the `data1` member of `fg` (which is 0)

And finally:

```
cout<<endl<<data1<<endl;
```

Displays the `data1` member of `f1` (which is 1)

Comment: The part 'data1 member of fg (which is 0)' is what confused me. You said data1++ bumped the value of f1 from 0 to 1, which I understood. When we say ff.display(which is same as f2.display), we get 5 because data1 is 5 for f2. Now when we say cout<<fg.data1, doesn't it mean, f1.data1 which is 1? fg=f1 right? f1 was passed inside f2.display() as an argument so I don't understand how data1 member of fg is 0..

Comment: Because `f2` and `f1` are copied, added that into the walk through. So the add 1 only affects `f1` .

Comment: Now I've got it. Thanks a ton. ^_^